# Use aggregate to obtain the fourth highest value per year in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data from of dates and values. I am trying to get the fourth highest value per year using dplyr and order or multiple aggregate statements. I want the date that the fourth highest value occurred on as well as the value in a data frame for all years.

Here is my script:

```
    timeozone <- import(i, date="DATES", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", header=TRUE, na.strings="NA")
    colnames(timeozone) <- c("column","date", "O3")
    timeozone %>%
      mutate(month = format(date, "%m"), day = format(date, "%d"), year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
      group_by(month, day, year) %>%
      summarise(fourth = O3[order(O3, decreasing = TRUE)[4] ])
```

I am not sure what is wrong with what I've got above. Any help would be appreciated.

Data:

> Dates         Values
>
> 11/12/2000     14
>
> 11/13/2000     16
>
> 11/14/2000     17
>
> 11/15/2000     21
>
> 11/13/2001     31
>
> 11/14/2001     21
>
> 11/15/2001     62
>
> 11/16/2001     14

Comment: Try `dplyr::nth()`.

Comment: In your edit, why are you grouping by `month` and `day`? I thought you wanted the fourth largest value per *year*. From the sample data you posted, there is no `03` column (is that `value`?) and it appears there is only one value per day -- there can be no fourth highest if that is the case. Try grouping by only `year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option with base (and using the iris data again) would be to split the variable by the group, then order it and extract the fourth element. For example

```
data(iris)
petals <- split(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species)
sapply(petals, function(x) x[order(x)][4])
```

or, actually, even more succinctly with `tapply`

```
tapply(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species, function(x) x[order(x)][4])
```

### Edit

Using the sample data above, you could extract the full row (or just the date, if you wanted), as follows.

```
date <- c("11/12/00", "11/13/00", "11/14/00", "11/15/00", "11/13/01", 
"11/14/01", "11/15/01", "11/16/01")

value <- c(14, 16, 17, 21, 31, 21, 62, 14)

date_splt <- strsplit(date, "/")
year <- sapply(date_splt, "[", 3)

d <- data.frame(date, value, year)

d_splt <- split(d, d$year)
lapply(d_splt, function(x) x[order(x$value), ][4, ])
```

Comment: Okay, I have daily data, how would I look at just a year?

Comment: Not sure I follow... Is Year the grouping variable? Or is day? Whatever the grouping variable is would go where Species is, and whatever the variable you want to extract the fourth element from would go where Petal.length is.

Comment: I now have the grouping variable as year after using mutate to get just one per year. But I need the entire date of the occurrence, not just the year, as specified above. I have edited the script to include this and have added data

Comment: It sounds like you just need to create a new date variable and put that where Petal.Length is, but I'm probably misunderstanding because I can't see your data and so I can't see the issue as you can. If you can post a sample of the data or simulate some that reasonably reflects yours I might be able to help further.

Comment: I posted sample data, above

Comment: I was hoping you'd post it in a more useable format. Regardless, I went ahead and illustrated how you could extract the whole date using `split`. If you wanted just the date you could, of course, replace `[4, ]` on the last line with `[4, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide reproducible data, here is an example using `iris`. You will need to group by your years instead of by `Species` but the same ideas apply.

You can do it relatively directly with `dplyr` if you are not wedded to `aggregate`:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(fourth = Petal.Length[order(Petal.Length, decreasing = TRUE)[4] ])
```

gives:

```
     Species fourth
1     setosa    1.7
2 versicolor    4.9
3  virginica    6.6
```

You can confirm that the values are correct using:

```
by(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species, sort)
```

Using `nth`, following the suggestion of @tchakravarty :

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(fourth = nth(sort(Petal.Length), -4L))
```

Gives the same value as above.

Comment: `dplyr` provides `nth` which is a far easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks -- I should have known there was a better way. Thanks for point it out to me.

Comment: You might want to check if you really need the `sort` in your answer.

Comment: But the fourth value per year? I have 20 years of data and am looking to get one value per year

Comment: I did try it without `sort` initially (just learning to play with `nth`), and it returns the 4th-from-the-end entry. Your suggestion (just deleted) to use `order_by = Petal.Length` instead of `sort`ing is a good option. I tend to think here that `sort` is more clear and less typing, but that is more opinion than objective difference.

Comment: @user6776063: Since you didn't provide reproducible data, here is an example using `iris`. You will need to group by your years instead of by `Species` but the same ideas apply. (added this to the answer as well)

Comment: Iris is your data frame?

Comment: `iris` is a builtin data.frame in R. If you just type in `iris` you should see it.